# Issue parsing JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have following json and i am having hard time parsing it in android.

```
{"Events":[
{"RecID":"0", "ItemDetail":[ 
    {"Title": "THRIC 2013"},
    {"Short_Detail" : "9TH ANNUAL TOURISM AND HOSPITALITY RESEARCH IN IRELAND CONFERENCE (THRIC)"},
    {"Long_Detail" : "The Tourism and Hospitality Research in Ireland Conference (THRIC) is an opportunity to gather industry, academia and students together and offers a forum to discuss their research. The 9th Annual Tourism and Hospitality Research in Ireland Conference (THRIC) will take place in Galway-Mayo Institute of Technology on Thursday 6th and Friday 7th June, 2013."},
    {"Programm":[ 
        {"EventDate":"06/06/2013", "Detail" :[
            {"ID" : "0", "Start_Time" : "08:30", "End_Time": "09:15", "Programme" : "Registration", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "1", "Start_Time" : "09:15", "End_Time": "10:15", "Programme" : "Conference Welcome & Official Opening", "Speaker" : "", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "2", "Start_Time" : "10:15", "End_Time": "11:00", "Programme" : "Keynote Speaker 1", "Speaker" : "0", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "3", "Start_Time" : "11:00", "End_Time": "11:30", "Programme" : "Morning Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "4", "Start_Time" : "11:30", "End_Time": "13:00", "Programme" : "Parallel Session A", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "5", "Start_Time" : "13:00", "End_Time": "14:15", "Programme" : "Networking Buffet Lunch", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Connemara Training Restaurant", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "6", "Start_Time" : "14:15", "End_Time": "15:00", "Programme" : "Keynote Speaker 2", "Speaker" : "1", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "7", "Start_Time" : "15:00", "End_Time": "15:15", "Programme" : "Afternoon Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "8", "Start_Time" : "15:15", "End_Time": "16:45", "Programme" : "Parallel Session B", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "9", "Start_Time" : "19:00", "End_Time": "00:00", "Programme" : "Drinks Reception", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "The G Hotel, Wellpark, Galway", "Map_Entry" : "53.281464, -9.032167"},
            {"ID" : "10", "Start_Time" : "19:30", "End_Time": "00:00", "Programme" : "Conference Dinner", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "The G Hotel, Wellpark, Galway", "Map_Entry" : "53.281464, -9.032167"}
        ]},
        {"EventDate":"07/06/2013", "ItemDetail":[
            {"ID" : "0", "Start_Time" : "08:30", "End_Time": "09:30", "Programme" : "Registration", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "1", "Start_Time" : "09:30", "End_Time": "11:00", "Programme" : "Parallel Session C", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "2", "Start_Time" : "11:00", "End_Time": "11:30", "Programme" : "Morning Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "3", "Start_Time" : "11:30", "End_Time": "12:45", "Programme" : "Panel Discussion", "Speaker" : "2,3,4,5,6", "Location" : "Rooms 939/Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "4", "Start_Time" : "12:45", "End_Time": "13:15", "Programme" : "Reflections on Conference\nClosing Address\nInvitation to THRIC 2014", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Room 939/Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "5", "Start_Time" : "13:15", "End_Time": "14:15", "Programme" : "Networking Buffet Lunch", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Connemara Training Restaurant", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "6", "Start_Time" : "14:15", "End_Time": "14:45", "Programme" : "ATHRI Committee Meeting", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "1031", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"Speakers":[ 
        {"ID" : "0", "Person_Name" : "Jim Murphy", "Title" : "CEO Prem Group", "Info" : "Jim Murphy is the CEO and founder of PREM Group,one of Irelands leading Hotel Management companies. A graduate of the Block Release Hotel Management Programme at GMIT, his association with what was to become PREM Group began in 1989 when he was appointed General Manager of Stephens Hall Hotel, Irelands first all-suite hotel. Prior to this appointment Jim had built up an admirable career gaining valuable management experience in renowned hotels such as ScotlandÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s Gleneagles Hotel, The Intercontinental Hotel Frankfurt, Marlfield House Hotel, Co. Wexford, Ireland, The Park Hotel, Co. Kerry, Ireland and the Gresham Hotel in DublinÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s city centre.\nIn 1996 Jim and fellow investors bought Stephens Hall Hotel and Jim was appointed Managing Director. This purchase marks the foundation of PREM Group. Today PREM Group operates over 40 properties in Ireland, England, Belgium, France and Poland. It is one of IrelandÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s largest hotel management companies and is working on a pipeline of new projects across Europe. PREM Group specialize in the management of hotels and serviced apartments under a number of major international brands such as, Crowne Plaza, Holiday Inn, Ramada Plaza, Days Hotels and Express by Holiday Inn. It also owns and operates its own brands under the name of Premier Apartments, Aspect Hotels and Leopold Hotels\nTrinity Purchasing, a wholly owned subsidiary of PREM Group, purchases goods and services to the value of Ã¢â€šÂ¬350m per annum. Trinity works with over 120 independent hotels delivering savings across a wide range of products.\nPREM Group recently secured a significant private equity investment into the company. This investment will be used to ramp up its growth strategy over the next few years.\nIn addition to growing PREM Group Jim has had the honour of holding the presidency of the Irish Hotels Federation from 2002 to 2004 and has been awarded a Fellowship of the Irish Hospitality Institute.\nFor more information see www.premgroup.com"},
        {"ID" : "1", "Person_Name" : "Mark Nagurski", "Title" : "Director Culture Tech Festival, Derry", "Info" : "Based in Derry, N. Ireland, Mark Nagurski is the Director of CultureTECH, a week-long festival of digital media, technology and music. CultureTECH features over 100 individual events with a total expected audience of over 30,000 people, making it one of the biggest digital events in the country. In addition to the festival, CultureTECH also manages a year-round programme of events and activities designed to foster innovation at the crossroads of culture and technology. Prior to launching CultureTECH, Mark served as Derry-Londonderry's first Digital Champion and currently sits on multiple boards and advisory groups across both technology and the arts."},
        {"ID" : "2", "Person_Name" : "John Concannon", "Title" : "Failte Ireland", "Info" : ""},
        {"ID" : "3", "Person_Name" : "Michael Vaughan", "Title" : "Irish Hotel Federation", "Info" : ""},
        {"ID" : "4", "Person_Name" : "Eammon McKeon", "Title" : "Irish Tourist Industry Confederation", "Info" : ""},
        {"ID" : "5", "Person_Name" : "John Crumlish", "Title" : "Galway Arts Festival", "Info" : ""},
        {"ID" : "6", "Person_Name" : "Tony Candon", "Title" : "National Museum of Ireland - Country Life", "Info" : ""}
    ]},
    {"eMail": "thric@gmit.ie"}, {"Post" : "THRIC Committee\nCollege of Tourism and Arts\nGalway-Mayo Institute of Technology\nDublin Road\nGalway\nIreland"}, {"Web" : "www.gmit.ie/thric"},{"Twitter":"@thric2013"}, {"GPS": "53.277801, -9.010624"}
    ]}
]}
```

I am trying to parse it using Jackson library...
The trouble i am having is when i am converting BufferReader to string using stringBuilder. Half of the data is being left out. I simply cannot understand the reason. My code is as follow....

```
private boolean callWebService()
{

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/thric/thric.php");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("Error", e1.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
    URLConnection urlc;
    try {
        urlc = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("Error", e1.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.i("data", line.toString());
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                sb.ensureCapacity(1000000);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
            return true;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        String result = sb.toString();

        Log.i("Data", result.toString());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
        try {

            AppData.getHandle().appData = mapper.readValue(result, Results.class);
            //AppData.getHandle().appData = mapper.readValue(result, Results.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
            return true;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
            return true;
        }
        return false;


    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("Error", e1.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can see in log info that the data is there in bufferreader but then half of it disappears... when appending lines to stringbuilder/stringbuffer. Please help.

The logCat info shows that the result is truncated as follows:

```
{"Events":[
{"RecID":"0", "ItemDetail":[ 
    {"Title": "THRIC 2013"},
    {"Short_Detail" : "9TH ANNUAL TOURISM AND HOSPITALITY RESEARCH IN IRELAND CONFERENCE (THRIC)"},
    {"Long_Detail" : "The Tourism and Hospitality Research in Ireland Conference (THRIC) is an opportunity to gather industry, academia and students together and offers a forum to discuss their research. The 9th Annual Tourism and Hospitality Research in Ireland Conference (THRIC) will take place in Galway-Mayo Institute of Technology on Thursday 6th and Friday 7th June, 2013."},
    {"Programm":[ 
        {"EventDate":"06/06/2013", "Detail" :[
            {"ID" : "0", "Start_Time" : "08:30", "End_Time": "09:15", "Programme" : "Registration", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "1", "Start_Time" : "09:15", "End_Time": "10:15", "Programme" : "Conference Welcome & Official Opening", "Speaker" : "", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "2", "Start_Time" : "10:15", "End_Time": "11:00", "Programme" : "Keynote Speaker 1", "Speaker" : "0", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "3", "Start_Time" : "11:00", "End_Time": "11:30", "Programme" : "Morning Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "4", "Start_Time" : "11:30", "End_Time": "13:00", "Programme" : "Parallel Session A", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "5", "Start_Time" : "13:00", "End_Time": "14:15", "Programme" : "Networking Buffet Lunch", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Connemara Training Restaurant", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "6", "Start_Time" : "14:15", "End_Time": "15:00", "Programme" : "Keynote Speaker 2", "Speaker" : "1", "Location" : "Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "7", "Start_Time" : "15:00", "End_Time": "15:15", "Programme" : "Afternoon Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "8", "Start_Time" : "15:15", "End_Time": "16:45", "Programme" : "Parallel Session B", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "9", "Start_Time" : "19:00", "End_Time": "00:00", "Programme" : "Drinks Reception", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "The G Hotel, Wellpark, Galway", "Map_Entry" : "53.281464, -9.032167"},
            {"ID" : "10", "Start_Time" : "19:30", "End_Time": "00:00", "Programme" : "Conference Dinner", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "The G Hotel, Wellpark, Galway", "Map_Entry" : "53.281464, -9.032167"}
        ]},
        {"EventDate":"07/06/2013", "ItemDetail":[
            {"ID" : "0", "Start_Time" : "08:30", "End_Time": "09:30", "Programme" : "Registration", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "1", "Start_Time" : "09:30", "End_Time": "11:00", "Programme" : "Parallel Session C", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Rooms 1041/1039/1033", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "2", "Start_Time" : "11:00", "End_Time": "11:30", "Programme" : "Morning Refreshments", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Theatre 1000 Foyer", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "3", "Start_Time" : "11:30", "End_Time": "12:45", "Programme" : "Panel Discussion", "Speaker" : "2,3,4,5,6", "Location" : "Rooms 939/Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "4", "Start_Time" : "12:45", "End_Time": "13:15", "Programme" : "Reflections on Conference\nClosing Address\nInvitation to THRIC 2014", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Room 939/Theatre 1000", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "5", "Start_Time" : "13:15", "End_Time": "14:15", "Programme" : "Networking Buffet Lunch", "Speaker" : "9999", "Location" : "Connemara Training Restaurant", "Map_Entry" : "53.277801, -9.010624"},
            {"ID" : "6", "St
```

Comment: What does the final result.toString() output? Is it the first half or the second half of your data?

Comment: @MattTaylor just added the output of result.toString()...

Comment: @AGilani r u sure it really disappears? i think sometimes logcat chops a string when it's too long to display.

Comment: It's working fine when printing to the console. I think @EntryLevelDev might be right.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev bummer, you are right... just tested it...
well then the issue is there is no error when mapping using objectmapper and yet data isn't there....

Comment: What type is the `AppData.getHandle().appData`? it should have the type of `Result.class` used to map the data.

Comment: @reidzeibel it is of Results.class... i am pretty new to this so i used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create POJO classes... and looking there, i do not suspect there is anything wrong with them saying that i am still in learning process so i might be wrong... but i looked through different examples on the internet and the POJO classes seems to be right...

Comment: Then maybe the data is not successfully passed into the variable, can you try passing the mapping result into other variable, such as `Results results = new Results();` and use `results=mapper.readValue(result,Results.Class)`, or try to implement a `Setter` like this : `AppData.getHandle().setAppData(mapper.readValue(result,Results.Class);`

Comment: I have checked the generator, try setting the `Source Type` as `JSON`, and `Annotation Style` as `None`. Also, tick the `Generate Builder Methods` and `Use Primitive Types`.

Comment: @reidzeibel yes tried that too... no avail...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30776/discussion-between-a-gilani-and-reidzeibel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `appData` variable might be re-initialized somewhere into a null value.

to prevent this, declare the `appData` before your `onCreate()` method like this :

`private Results appData = new Results();`

then on your `callWebService()` method, pass JSON mapping like this :

`AppData.getHandle().setAppData(mapper.readValue(result, Results.class));`

Good Luck ^^